# How do I know inferred type in Kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, types, kotlin, type-inference

(I use Kotlin 1.1.2-2)

For example, how do I know the inferred type of expression `if (boolean_value) 1 else 2.0`? `kotlinc-jvm` doesn't show the type. `javaClass` also doesn't help because it shows the type of computed value not expression.

```
>>> (if (true) 1 else 2.0).javaClass.name
java.lang.Integer
>>> (if (false) 1 else 2.0).javaClass.name
java.lang.Double
>>> val v: Double = if (false) 1 else 2.0
error: the integer literal does not conform to the expected type Double
val v: Double = if (false) 1 else 2.0
                       ^
```

Answer (score 6):

when assign the if expression with diff type result to an implicit primitive variable (*variable without type definition*) then the variable type is `Any`/`T?`, or an implicit variable with their direct supper class `P`. for example:

```
// case 1
val v = if (false) 1 else 2.0
//  ^--- Any
v.toInt(); // error because v is Any

// case 2
val v = if (false) 1 else null
//  ^--- Int?

// case 3
val e = if (true) java.sql.Time(1) else java.sql.Timestamp(1);
//  ^--- its type is java.util.Date
```

but you can define the variable explicitly with their superclass, for example:

```
// case 1
val v:Number = if (false) 1 else 2.0;
v.toInt();//ok 

// case 2
val v:Int? = if (false) 1 else null;
```

*Note*: you can also using `CTRL+SHIFT+P`/`CTRL+Q` to see the variable type quickly in IDEA.

Comment: Type hints were introduced in IDEA with the new Kotlin v1.1.3 released yesterday. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/06/kotlin-1-1-3-is-out/#more-5080

Comment: the type shown by IDEA is same as the type inferred by Kotlin compiler? or just a type computed by the plugin? IDEA shows parent type for `if (...) child1 else child2` not `Any`.

Comment: @letrec what's version of your kotlin now? mine is `1.1.2-5`.

Comment: @holi-java I use IDEA 2017.1.4 build IC-171.4694.23 + Kotlin plugin 1.1.2. Classes are `open class MyBool`, `class MyTrue : MyBool()` and `class MyFalse : MyBool()`.

Comment: I think you people will love this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851861/how-do-i-activate-type-annotations-hints-in-kotlin-like-depicted/54852497#54852497

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165263

You can use the `is` operator to check whether an object is of a specific type:

```
val number = 5
if(number is Int) {
   println("number is of type Int")
}
```

You can also get the type as `String` using reflection:

```
println("${number::class.simpleName}")    // "Int"
println("${number::class.qualifiedName}") // "kotlin.Int"
```

Please note:

> On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the
> reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file
> (kotlin-reflect.jar). This is done to reduce the required size of the
> runtime library for applications that do not use reflection features.
> If you do use reflection, please make sure that the .jar file is added
> to the classpath of your project.

Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11