# Get type of a variable in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, instanceof

How can I find the variable type in Kotlin?
In Java there is `instanceof`, but in Kotlin it does not exist:

```
val properties = System.getProperties() // Which type?
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
val value="value"
println(value::class.java.typeName)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This adds nothing new to the matter. You just use `typeName` of `java.lang.Class<T>` instead of the `qualifiedName` of `KCLass<T>` (more Kotlin-ish) as I've shown in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165263/1788806 which was the previously chosen one.

Comment: @WilliMentzel Your answer is perfect and idiomatic. I don't have any idea why this one is chosen!

Comment: This solution requires Android O (API 26) or newer.

Answer (score 118):

You can use the [`is` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators) to check whether an object is of a specific type:

```
val number = 5
if(number is Int) {
   println("number is of type Int")
}
```

You can also get the type as `String` using reflection:

```
println(Int::class.simpleName)    // "Int"
println(Int::class.qualifiedName) // "kotlin.Int"
```

Please note:

> On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the
> reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file
> (kotlin-reflect.jar). This is done to reduce the required size of the
> runtime library for applications that do not use reflection features.
> If you do use reflection, please make sure that the .jar file is added
> to the classpath of your project. [(Source)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11)

Answer (score 4):

you can get the class name with `properties::class.simpleName`

Comment: You can also use properties.javaClass.simpleName

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor detail between mentioned answers.

```
var x = "X"
println(x::class.simpleName) // prints String
```

This code uses Reflection under the hood when you decompile it to Java bytecode and it looks like this `Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(x.getClass()).getSimpleName()`

```
var y = "Y"
println(y.javaClass.simpleName) // prints String
```

And this would compile down to `y.getClass().getSimpleName()` and it's about 50 milliseconds faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the class type in Kotlin (as opposed to Java):

```
val value="value"
println(value::class)
```