# What is the equivalent of type() function from python in kotlin?

Tags: python, kotlin

I am just beginning to learn Kotlin, I am a total novice having no experience in Java. I know python so I can't help but compare the two while learning. Can anyone please specify the equivalent of the **type()** function (used to return the type of a variable) from Python, if any, present in Kotlin?

Comment: Could you give an example of where you'd need this?  (In a strongly-typed language like Kotlin, there are often better approaches.)

Comment: I currently don't have one, as I said, I am learning so my brain is just trying to compare it with python.

Answer (score 5):

`::class` would be the equivalent I think - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Eg

```
val greeting = "hello"
val greetingType = greeting::class
```

Note that there are other useful type related operations such as

```
if (greeting is String)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the reflections to get the type names as String.

```kotlin
val str = "I am a String"
val reflection = str::class

println(reflection.qualifiedName)  // kotlin.String
println(reflection.simpleName)     // String
```

[Play with the code yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/E-9slLpyV).

PS: More about [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/), and for more information about reflection see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Answer (score 1):

For finding the type of any object you can use `is` keyword.
For better understanding,please refer to [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165143/get-type-of-a-variable-in-kotlin/45165263)