# How do I activate type annotations hints in Kotlin like depicted?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I was able to activate this option once in my MacOS intellij version, but could never find this option anymore, I forgot its name.

I know there is the CTRL+SHIFT+P alternative to this, but it is not as user-friendly.

How can I activate the option to make intellij show me all the inferred types like depicted? This screenshot came out of the intellij where I was able to put it showing "type hints" like this, so it is possible. I just don't remember where to find this option anymore so I can activate in all my other intellij's.

[image]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For **IntelliJ (2022.1)** onwards got to `Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Types -> Kotlin -> Types -> Parameter hints -> Local variable types` or check all.

I think you are allowed to say, that this feature configuration is a little bit hidden in the menues and was moved a lot between different releases.

[image: Configure parameter name hints]

Thanks to @vitfo, adding this to the top here. For **IntelliJ (2020.3)** onwards got to:
`Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Kotlin -> Parameter hints -> Types`

In **IntelliJ 2019.3.1** onwards it is located at:
`Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Kotlin -> "Show parameter hints"` (thanks to @zero).

**Original Answer for IntelliJ 2018**
Go to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> "Show parameter name hints" -> Configure... -> Language: Kotlin -> Options -> "Show local variable type hints"`

Comment: Note that this also works for Android Studio, at least 3.4.2.

Comment: I mistakenly enabled them and they annoyed me, but I had no idea how to get rid of them. Thank you!

Comment: This is apparently different now in IntelliJ 20. Looks to be under _"Editor"_ -> _"Inlay Hints"_ -> _"Kotlin"_.

Answer (score 41):

Adding to @Simulant answer.

In **Latest Version of IntelliJ (2019.3.1)** , You will NOT find this in `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> "Show parameter name hints"`

Its available in `Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Kotlin -> "Show parameter hints"`

[image]

Answer (score 29):

Adding to @Simulant and @zero answers

In the latest version of **IntelliJ (2020.3)** you need to go to `Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints` where you can specify *"Show hints for"* (for specific language) and then in `Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Kotlin -> Parameter hints -> Types` you can specify what type of hints you want.

[image]